# Show meeting as out of office from outlook inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

I sometimes receive invites in Outlook 2010 that I want to accept and have the time shown as `Out of Office` instead of `Busy`.  Currently, I accept the invite and then go into the calendar view, find the meeting, open it and change the `Show as` field.  As the invite might be weeks or even months away, finding the meeting can take a bit of effort.

Is there a way to set the `Show As` value when I am reading the invite in the Mail view?

I have tried clicking and right clicking on the obvious (to me) places, but have not found anything useful.